# Using csv.reader on clipboard data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I use csv.reader successfully on a .csv file but if I copy the contents of the same file to the clipboard using Notepad++ and feed that to the csv.reader, I get a different result. Each character on the string gets written to a separate row.

e.g.

```
import csv
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

board = csv.reader(data, dialect='excel')
for row in board:
    print(','.join(row))
```

Any ideas? Thank you already.

Comment: How does your `data` look like? Which type das it have? Most probably its a string, and as an iterator it yields single characters. Files yield lines.

Comment: Well I just fill in 4 cells in Excel, 2 rows by 2 columns. If you copy this to the clipboard it is like this: 'ABC\tDEF\r\nGHI\tJKL\r\n'. It is a string but includes CR, LF and tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you hand `csv.reader` a string, but [it expects some iterable that yields a line for every call of `next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).
A string is iterable, but yields one character each.

The solution is to hand `csv.reader` a list of lines:

```
board = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), dialect="excel")
```